# How to make sure Skype call with share desktop work smoothly between two countries?

Tags: skype

Skype has a special user called Skype Test Call which helps us to test whether we can make a call normally with our headphone - the speaker and microphone is working.

Though I often have problem with internet calls with my foreign customers i.e. calls between two different countries. It is very good when testing with Skype Test Call though not that good when in the real call.

Even worst, with desktop sharing turned on, the call is almost impossible to continue.

So my question is how can I ensure that I can make Skype conference with my clients in another country with desktop sharing?

Comment: You need a good internet connection/bandwidth at both ends ... what are the two countries?

Comment: How to define 'good connection' then? The two are Saigon, Vietnam and some city in Austalia, Europe, and United State